# I have more than 300 tables in my schema and i need to run a truncate command

Tags: mysql

I have more than 300 tables in my schema and i need to run a truncate command? how is this possible I need to know all foreign keys and sort the table in oreder of there dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME | while read table; do mysql -e "truncate table $table" DATABASE_NAME; done
```

Comment: Miqdad Ali Sorry Miqdad I only need to truncate the transaction tables......Thanks for your help